# MongoDB NestJS API dies if a @Prop is set to ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, api, mongoose, nestjs, objectid

So, when i set a `@Prop()` to `ObjectId`, the api wont start, but if i set it a `string` it loads up just fine.

Can you help me? Thanks!

Heres the error:

[image: error]

**Schema:**

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { Document, ObjectId } from "mongoose";

export type FriendRequestDocument = FriendRequest & Document;

@Schema({collection: "friendRequests"})
export class FriendRequest {
  @Prop()
  author: ObjectId;

  @Prop()
  friend_id: ObjectId;

  @Prop()
  request_at: Date;
}

export const FriendRequestSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(FriendRequest);
```

**edit:**
[image: error]

**I figured it out!**

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import mongoose, { Document, ObjectId } from "mongoose";

export type FriendRequestDocument = FriendRequest & Document;

@Schema({collection: "friendRequests"})
export class FriendRequest {
  @Prop()
  author: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop()
  friend_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop()
  request_at: Date;
}

export const FriendRequestSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(FriendRequest);
```

I dont really know why its not working.

Comment: use `Schema.Types.ObjectId` [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)

Comment: Not working. im gonna update the question and put a picture there

Comment: I figured it out! It works with ```Mongoose.Types.ObjectId```, Thanks!

Comment: @NoelMaróti  You can answer your own question, then others can see there's a working solution.

Comment: FYI, it's better to include code/errors/tracebacks/etc. in codeblocks rather than images.  You can just copy/paste the text.

Comment: Okay, i will do that in the future